# ScrollReveal.js not working on Safari with <svg> elements

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-transforms, scrollreveal.js

I'm currently using ScrollReveal.js to make a bunch of tiny pixelated boxes do random things when scrolled upon, with the following code:

```
var index=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.pixel-box').each(function() { //each tiny box has class pixel-box
        var directions =[ 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom']

        index += 1

        var currentElement = $(this);
        var randEffect = getRandomInt(0,1);
        var randTime = getRandomArbitrary(1, 3.5);
        var randDirection = getRandomInt(0,3);

        if(randEffect == 0){
            var rand = getRandomInt(-360, 360);
            $(this).attr('data-sr', 'wait .5s, enter ' + directions[randDirection] + ', flip ' + rand + 'deg, over '+ randTime +'s');
    }
        else if(randEffect == 1){
            // move 24px
             var rand = getRandomInt(10, 120);
            $(this).attr('data-sr', 'wait .5s, enter ' + directions[randDirection] +', move '+ rand + 'px, over '+ randTime +'s');
        }


        if(index == 81){
             window.sr = new scrollReveal();
        }
    });
});
```

It's working perfectly on Chrome, but on Safari, the behavior is extremely clunky and not what I want. Would you or anyone else have any insights as to why this is happening?

To illustrate, here's what it looks like on Chrome:

https://gyazo.com/4f51ff8279cf5a76ad3ab38a680ae2af

Here's what it looks like on Safari:

https://gyazo.com/8c30e489a2470ac415da3dde1d95d4ef

For reference, one of these boxes is being rendered using the HTML code:

```
<rect class="pixel-box" id="Rectangle-167-Copy-7" fill="#FDD93D" filter="url(#filter-35)" x="823.65422" y="188.994877" width="16.675" height="19.0983607"></rect>
```

I suspect that the problem may be due to inconsistencies with CSS transformations and SVG elements like `<rect>` and `<path>` across different browsers, but I haven't been coming up with much.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a browser issue with Safari animating opacity and transforms at the same time.

> ...we came across a particularly frustrating bug in Safari involving
>   animation of SVG elements using CSS3 transforms and opacity
>   simultaneously.
>
> Safari will not animate both attributes at the same time, instead
>   choosing to animate the opacity with the correct timings and when that
>   animation is complete the transform jumps to its correct position, or
>   the translation is just ignored completely.

Reference: https://www.theparticlelab.com/safari-svg-animation-bug/

Looks like others have had [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983182/possible-to-animate-two-properties-of-an-svg-at-once-with-a-css-animation) in the past, but the [browser bug appears fixed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319407).